# Group by clause in HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

How to write the given sql in HQL in hibernate and get an array of object which contains two columns

```
select specialization, count(specialization) 
from ocs_tbl_doctor group by specialization;
```

Mapping Bean class is

**DoctorBean.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OCS_TBL_DOCTOR")
public class DoctorBean {

@Id
@Column(name = "DOCTORID")
private String doctorID;

@Column(name = "DOCTORNAME")
private String doctorName;

@Column(name = "DATEOFBIRTH")
private Date dateOfBirth;

@Column(name = "DATEOFJOINING")
private Date dateOfJoining;

@Column(name = "GENDER")
private String gender;

@Column(name = "QUALIFICATION")
private String qualification;

@Column(name = "SPECIALIZATION")
private String specialization;

@Column(name = "YEARSOFEXPERIENCE")
private int yearsOfExperience;

@Column(name = "STREET")
private String street;

@Column(name = "LOCATION")
private String location;

@Column(name = "CITY")
private String city;

@Column(name = "STATE")
private String state;

@Column(name = "PINCODE")
private String pincode;

@Column(name = "CONTACTNUMBER")
private String contactNumber;

@Column(name = "EMAILID")
private String emailID;

//getters and setters
}
```

I am having problem in projecting the second column i.e (count(specialization))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select d.specialization, count(d.specialization) 
from DoctorBean d  group by d.specialization;
```

Comment: just affect a list to your result query

Comment: Thank you it worked!!!. i just output the object and it displayed the value i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-grouping).

```
select doc.specialization, count(doc)
from DoctorBean doc
group by doc.specialization
```